# SVN for Dummies (me)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I wan't to start using SVN.

I've been reading about it, and installed Tortoise on my windows machine.

What I need to understand though, is where to create my repository if the folder I want to manage is in var/www/vhost/domain.com/httpdocs/

I don't quite grasp the concept of a repository, so if I could have a pointer from you guys in the right direction it would help me a lot.

Comment: I'm not trolling you, but unless svn is part of your job/team/company, I have a hard time recommending svn over git or mercurial for new projects.  (i.e. use it for legacy projects if you don't feel like making the conversion to a new SCM.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [High-Speed Tutorial](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.intro.quickstart.html) is available but if you're new to version control you may want to check [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.basic.html) before.

Although it is written for the command line, it should be quite easy to find the equivalent operations in Tortoise, except perhaps for the `$ svnadmin create repos` that probably needs
to be run from a shell (maybe by root, depending on where you `create`).

The repository may be created anywhere you like but preferably in a safe place, not /var/www. As hinted by Chris you may (and should) instead checkout a working copy there. I also suggest that you use a separate checkout (maybe in your login directory) for development.

Answer (score 1):

The repository is the central master copy of the source that contains the change history.  you should place it in a location where it can grow and be backed up easily.

The working copy is the version you will be editing that contains .svn folders in each subfolder.  This is created by doing a checkout.

The deployed folder (in your case "/var/www/vhost/domain.com/httpdocs/") can be the working copy or an "export"ed copy.  If you use the deployed folder as a working folder be sure you secure the .svn folders from being served via HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Create your repository anywhere else, preferably on a different server that is regularly backed up. Then you make your existing httpdocs into a working copy for that repository, according to [these instructions](http://www.principia-it.co.uk/tools-n-tips/subversion/subversion-faq/7-subversion/16-how-do-i-convert-an-existing-directory-into-a-working-copy).